# Rotate text in IE, without it getting ugly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, css

I'd like to rotate a text by 90 degrees counter-clockwise. Firefox and Chrome are no problem, using:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

For Internet Explorer, it should be this line, as far as I know:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

(The other method, **writing-mode**, can only rotate text clockwise 90 degrees).

However, in IE the rotated text looks like a badly scaled image on its side (comparison below).

[image: Firefox/Chrome] Firefox / Chrome -- vs -- Internet Explorer: [image: Internet Explorer]

Is there any way that Internet Explorer can rotate the text in a more elegant way (possibly Javascript/jQuery)? I've been Googling, but I can only find more references to this method...

Comment: Make sure your final rotated element is pixel-aligned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RenderEngine of IE is awful... I would try to work with background images. Maybe a **Font Replacement** like [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) would do a better Job. Cufon generates Images of your Text. Works good in IE as far as i know.

Comment: Text rendered as images is difficult for users who use accessibility aids, such as screen readers.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I think I'll go with this type of solution. With the function imagettftext you can already define the angle at which the image should be rendered. It does require a separate file, as if using an actual image (title.php). As for the accessibility aids, this text is for the title of the page, which is the same as its corresponding menu-item, so I think in this case it is not that big a deal.

Comment: @jeffamaphone That is in this situation not correct because Cufon leaves the Text as it is. Cufon added via JS some extra elements which contains the images. The Only minus on Cufon is you can not select the text.

Comment: Another minus is that you can't change the color using CSS

Answer (score 36):

It is Def the text rendering engine in IE; however, it's doable.

**filter:** requires the element to have **layout** (ie. zoom). You can beat the rendering problem (most of the time), by giving the element a background color. Try the following on your example:

```
zoom:1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
background-color:white;
```

Comment: +1 It does help a little. Unfortunately, it is not yet as clean as Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: :-) it is IE we're talking about here. The solution works, but it has its own set of pros/cons. Pros all revolve around accessibility and as few lines of code as possible. Cons all revolve around presentation.

Comment: +1 Adding the background-color works well for me. It's readable now, before it was a mess. Didn't want to have to add another layer of complexity with Cufon, etc.

Comment: Adding a background color solved it for us as well! Thank you for this great tip!!

Comment: If you want to use the background color of the parent, you can use: background-color: inherit; this will work and also change when the parent changes it's background color (when hovering for example).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either Google Fonts API or Cufon (as @swishmiller said), **or** disabling Anti-Aliasing (ClearType) in IE so the fonts always look unsmoothed (is that a word)?

Google Font API: http://code.google.com/webfonts

Cufon: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Disable ClearType:

```
    /* This will force IE into thinking there is a filter actually doing something, so it'll disable ClearType */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)";
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
```

**[edit]** I should mention that I've not tried the Google Font API fix...

Comment: The Disable ClearType thing sounded promising, but we did not see any difference...

Comment: Wow, this is officially the longest wait for a comment ever! - 2.5 years

Answer (score 0):

Try -ms-writing-mode property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx