# Text rotate background issue - IE8 and IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, carousel

I have a carousel that requires titles be rotated by 270 degrees, and it looks lovely but on IE8 & IE7, there is a horrible black outline in the text.

From Firefox- IE9, Chrome and opera are all identical ->
[image: image from FF, identical in IE9, Opera and Chrome]

From IE8, IE7 shows the same. ->
[image: From IE8, IE7 is exactly the same]

I have tried the css method `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);` but this screws up IE9, even with `-ms-transform` in there to counter it.

I have also-

- Included Cufon to try to create an image canvas of the text, then rotate that using css filters/transforms - same result.
- Used jQuery Rotate plugin from [jQuery Rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

If anyone has any ideas on how to overcome this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks, 
Dan

Comment: seems like a rendering issue. i had many problems of this type and i everytime i ended up by using images on ie 7 and 8 :( maybe blur filter could help - don't know the ie 7 and 8 support

Comment: I wouldn't worry about IE7. As for IE8 use this :-) http://browserawarenessday.com/#code

Comment: The blur does look like the right direction but it is too strong, even at 1px it smudges too much, you can't read the text. It appears to be the Alpha channel that's screwing up. I can't quite seem to work out how to apply the AlphaImageLoader filter in this case.

Comment: @strah - Generally, I wouldn't worry but IE7 is a requirement for this project.

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4901572/852866

Comment: Spot on. Thanks @Strah -> worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Raphael http://raphaeljs.com/
I've used this in some projects and have had good experiences.