# How to stop transform-rotation from distorting font?

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I'm using transform-rotation css property to rotate a a div so i can use it as a fixed facebook and twitter links on my page, altho, when i use it it "distorts" my current text font. When i take the rotation off, text goes back to normal. Is there a way to fix this!?

[**Here is my website.**](http://www.datamaia.pt/)

My divs are social[[facebook],[twitter]].

Here's the css for inner divs:

```
#facebook,#twitter{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:125px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

And here's the css for socials:

```
#social{
position:absolute;
right:-120px;
bottom:50%;
transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

All i want is the text to appear clear crystal and not all distorted. Is there another way to do this that won't change/distort my font!?

Comment: Looks fine to me in FF/Mac. I don't see a background color on the rotated text though -- perhaps that will help. Check out this previous answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899442/rotate-text-in-ie-without-it-getting-ugly/4901572#4901572

Comment: what browser (and version) are you testing with? This kind of thing is always going to based on the capabilities of the browser's rendering engine, and will thus be very browser-specific.

Comment: using chrome, last version i'm pretty sure. So, chrome uses an engine to render text!?

Answer (score 1):

When we rotate an element, some of webfonts get this kind of distortion. You can try apply `backface-visibility:hidden` to solve this distortion. Hope to help you!

Here is an example:

```css
.fix-language{
    font-family:"Arial", sans-serif;
 position: absolute;
 left: -90px;
    top:120px;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }
 .fix-language ul{
    list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 }
 .fix-language ul li{
    display:inline-block;
 margin-right:15px;
 }
 .fix-language ul li a{
    color:$black-color;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fix-language">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portugues</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```